# Is there a way to stop a screen reader from reading past a certain point?

Tags: reactjs, screen-readers

I have working on a page in react that has certain popups. When users use a screen reader it defaults to read the popup straight away but then if the user keeps hitting next they eventually get down to the rest of the page.

I want the visually impaired user to know that they have reached the end of the popup so they know that they have been given all the information for that section.

Is there a way to stop a screen reader from going past a certain div in react?

I should also mention that the exit button and the fact the user is in a popup is made very clear. I just want them to know they've hit the end.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a way to stop a screen reader from going past a certain div in react?

It sounds like you are describing more of a modal window than a popup. If this is the case, you could experiment with the `aria-modal` ARIA attribute.  I'd suggest you read this [Paciello Group article](https://developer.paciellogroup.com/blog/2018/06/the-current-state-of-modal-dialog-accessibility/) for some history and caveats. This working [ARIA example](https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria-practices/examples/dialog-modal/dialog.html) may also be helpful if you choose to go this route.

If you just want to warn screen reader users that they've hit the end of a popup (while still allowing them to go past it), you could simply provide hidden instructions. I'd suggest using the first method on the [US government's 18F](https://accessibility.18f.gov/hidden-content/) page.

Good luck!